# Присоединительная конструкция

Tags: запятая

Нужно ли в предложении слово *например* выделять запятыми или это присоединительная конструкция:

> Программы, которые уже действуют в
> районе по моей поддержке и инициативе,
> будут продолжены, как например уже
> ранее упомянутая "Планета детства".

Comment: @Верьясова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В "Русской грамматике":

Отношения включения без присоединительного оттенка выражаются устойчивыми сочетаниями *как например*, *такие как*, а также (редко) союзом *как*; при этом второй член всегда имеет форму им. п.:

Совершенно посторонние люди, как Ершовы, оказали нам самое горячее участие (В. Поленов);

Первые азиатские революции произошли не в колониях, а в полуколониальных странах, таких как Иран, Турция и Китай (газ.);

По предметам крестьянского быта, как например туесок из бересты или прялка, легко узнать сибирскую деревню (газ.).

В свое время мною был задан вопрос насчет выражения *как например* на сайте http://gramma.ru/. Вот что мне ответили:

Чтобы понять всю ту путаницу, которая существует вокруг употребления сочетания "как например", необходимо иметь в виду, что очень длительное время оно употреблялось только в расчлененном виде. Изменения в трактовке этого сочетания начались на рубеже XX и XXI века, их следствием стали изменения в его пунктуационном оформлении. До сих пор при оформлении сочетания смешиваются старые и новые принципы.

Внимания заслуживают два случая:

1) Слова_как например_, *например*, *как то*, *а именно*, употребляются в качестве пояснительных союзов после обобщающего слова

При обобщающих словах могут быть уточняющие слова *как например*, 
*например*, *как то*, *а именно*, перед которыми ставится запятая, а после них 
двоеточие.

Слова *как например*, *как то* употребляются для пояснения предшествующих 
слов, слова *а именно* для указания на исчерпывающий характер последующего
перечисления:

Круглосуточно работают многие предприятия и службы, как например: связь, скорая помощь, больницы.

Эти детские книги помогут вам обсудить с детьми многие темы, как например: дружба, взаимопомощь, семья.

2)) в качестве вводного сочетания, вводящего оборот со значением включения (условно его можно отнести к пояснению или уточнению):

Целые тушки -- в свежем, маринованном, жареном или копченом виде -- или 
просто отдельные их части, как например всеми любимые окорочка, крылышки или 
грудки.

По предметам крестьянского быта, как например туесок из бересты или прялка, легко узнать сибирскую деревню (газ.).

В первом случае после оборота ставится двоеточие; во втором случае оборот должен целиком включаться в состав обособленного члена предложения.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых. Запятыми слово *например* выделить нужно.

Во-вторых. *"Как, например..."* лучше перенести поближе к программам:

***Программы, которые уже действуют в районе по моей поддержке и инициативе, -- как,например, уже ранее упомянутая "Планета детства" -- будут продолжены.***

В-третьих. На мой взгляд, плохо *"**Программы**, которые уже **действуют** в районе **по моей поддержке и инициативе**".* Программы могли быть *начаты, созданы, запущены* **"по"** *моей* *инициативе,* но действуют-то они не **"по"** *моей поддержке...*

Лучше было бы вообще убрать *"мою поддержку и инициативу":*

***Программы, которые уже действуют в районе, -- как,например, уже ранее упомянутая "Планета детства" -- будут продолжены.***

Можно *"мою"* частично сохранить:

***Начатые по моей инициативе  районные программы, в том числе и ранее упомянутая программа "Планета детства", будут продолжены.***

Но если попытаться засунуть в это предложение и *"мою поддержку",*  предложение будет смотреться очень тяжело. ИМХО.

Comment: Огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Если присоединительная конструкция начинается с вводного слова "например, в частности, главным образом", то запятой отделяется вся присоединительная конструкция, то есть после вводного слова запятая не ставится. В Вашем же случае слово "например" стоит на втором месте, поэтому запятыми слово "например" отделяется: 
"Программы, которые уже действуют в районе по моей поддержке и инициативе, будут продолжены, как,например, уже ранее упомянутая "Планета детства".

Comment: Все понятно, я что-то немного забыла это правило, вернее, меня сбил союз как.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.